# AS3 Cicyle days of week

Tags: actionscript-3, text

So i have this code can somewone tell me i am doing this right. Sometimes  when i change date the code in text gives me null. i am trying to cycle days of week inside four text fields, so it will be day for today is hidden and text boxes displays tommorow day and next days after tommorow here is the code:

```
var dayOfWeek_array:Array = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wensday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
var today_date:Date = new Date();

var day_str:String = dayOfWeek_array[today_date.getDay()+0];
var day_str1:String = dayOfWeek_array[today_date.getDay()+1];
var day_str2:String = dayOfWeek_array[today_date.getDay()+2];
var day_str3:String = dayOfWeek_array[today_date.getDay()-4];
var day_str4:String = dayOfWeek_array[today_date.getDay()-3];



myTextField1.text = (""+day_str1);
myTextField2.text = (""+day_str2);
myTextField3.text = (""+day_str3);
myTextField4.text = (""+day_str4);
```

Comment: well, what do you mean with sometimes it gives you null? when exactly does it to day?

Comment: well try to change date on your computer is this a correct code i was initial having code dayOfWeek_array[today_date.getDay()+0];
than +1, +2, +3, +4 and that gave me null instead of Sunday name

Answer (score 1):

For day 3 and day 4, you do a SUBTRACTION. Which means that if the day of the week is 2, and you decrease it by 4, you get index of -2. The array doesn't have such an index. And it should give you out of bounds error :)

Comment: Come on man, check your code! :) day_str3: `today_date.getDay()-4` - should be `+4`. And day_str4 is even worse: `today_date.getDay()-3`, where it's about to be `+5`....

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to do. Today is Friday, `getDay()` function will return `5`. If you want to show the next day, it will be `6`, which in the array is `Saturday`. If you want to have Sunday, you will need to provide ZERO (`0`), as it's in the first index of the array!
If you want to show the next day, create new Date object: `new Date(today.fullYear, today.month, today.day + 1)` - it will automatically parse everything, even if it's 31st and you add one day - it will change month, etc..

Answer (score 0):

You need to 'wrap' your 'getDay() + N' value to ensure it is always in the range 0-6.
i.e.

```
var tmp = today_date.getDay() + 3;
if(tmp > 6) tmp -= 7;
var day_str3:String = dayOfWeek_array[tmp];
```

(You could probably have a more robust solution using modulus, but for this situation this solution clear and simple)

Comment: still gave me null if you can write me the code iam doing something wrong

Comment: i also ask the question with your example code but still cant get it work

Comment: @user3391599 I used day_str3 as an example but you also need to change day_str4 to  dayOfWeek_array[today_date.getDay()+4];