# AS3 day of week shuffle

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Having some issues in code. I am trying to shuffle days of week in four dynamic text boxes so if today is thursday other box shows friday and other after that shows saturday, sunday... And the days shuffle but when its comes to sunday my code shows null instead day name, where did i go wrong? here is a code:

```
var dayOfWeek_array:Array = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wensday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
var today_date:Date = new Date();
var day_str:String = dayOfWeek_array[today_date.getDay()+0];
var day_str1:String = dayOfWeek_array[today_date.getDay()+1];
var day_str2:String = dayOfWeek_array[today_date.getDay()+2];


var tmp1 = today_date.getDay() + 3;
if(tmp1 > 6) tmp -= 7;
var day_str3:String = dayOfWeek_array[tmp];

var tmp = today_date.getDay() + 4;
if(tmp > 6) tmp -= 7;
var day_str4:String = dayOfWeek_array[tmp];

myTextField1.text = (""+day_str1);
myTextField2.text = (""+day_str2);
myTextField3.text = (""+day_str3);
myTextField4.text = (""+day_str4);
```

Comment: I see you used my solution from [your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22830722/as3-cicyle-days-of-week). How about accepting the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would point you to the modulo operator: % http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#modulo

Using that you can do something like  `dayOfWeek_array[(today_date.getDay()+0) % 7];`

This will always return number between 0 and 6, so, you won't get nulls in your text fields

Different story is, that I would put your textfields in array, so you can manage them using cycles. With that, you can easily change behaviour or number of fields in the future.

Comment: Just replace your `dayOfWeek_array[today_date.getDay()+0]` with `dayOfWeek_array[(today_date.getDay()+0) % 7]`, `dayOfWeek_array[today_date.getDay()+1]` with `dayOfWeek_array[(today_date.getDay()+1) % 7]`, etc. 
Then you can get rid of all that `tmp` and `tmp1` stuff

You can ignore end of my answer ("Different story") for now, but I would strongly encourage reading about arrays, because in the future, you will hate yourself for this code :)

Answer (score 1):

You should learn how to reuse code. You don't have logic for situations, when index is out of bounds.

Here is small example how to create utility function, that will return element of the array with offset:

```
var days:Array = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
var today:Date = new Date();

//Test
trace(offset(today.day, days)); //Thursday
trace(offset(today.day, days, 1)); //Friday
trace(offset(today.day, days, -1)); //Wednesday
trace(offset(today.day, days, 8)); //Friday
trace(offset(today.day, days, -8)); //Wednesday

function offset(position:int, items:Array, offset:int = 0):Object {
    var size:int = items.length;

    //Apply offset
    position += offset % size;
    if (position < 0) {
        position += size;
    } else if (position >= size) {
        position %= size;
    }

    return items[position];
}
```